# Cake PHP incompatibility with SQL SERVER

Tags: php, cakephp, functional-programming

Good evening, I'm doing a query in the sql server using CakePHP using query() function, to return the query result to a View, the index of the array is not the name of the Model, so every time I try to iterate on return, the same faulted in the index.
See:

//Model

```
 public function select(){
            $query = "select SUM(VL_TEMPO_CPU) AS 'TOTAL' from eps.tb_tarefa_log as Tarefa
                      where no_tarefa='CD/A/PC/47' AND YEAR(DT_TAREFA)='2013'
                      GROUP BY MONTH(DT_TAREFA);";
            //query de consulta 
            return($this->query($query));
            //var_dump($result);
            //return($result);
        }
```

#

//View

```
<h2>Tarefa</h2>

<table>
    <!-- Nome das colunas -->
    <tr>
            <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
<?php 

    //Correr por todos os registros cadastrados
    foreach($registros as $reg ){
        var_dump($reg);    
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$reg['Tarefa']['Total']}</td></tr>";
    }
?>

</table>
```

#

Array value:

```
   array(1) { 
        [0]=> array(1) { 
            ["TOTAL"]=> string(18) "5.4782208763062954" 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is same for MySQL as well. You need to use virtual fields:

```
public function select(){

    $query = "select SUM(VL_TEMPO_CPU) AS Tarefa__TOTAL from eps.tb_tarefa_log as Tarefa
              where no_tarefa='CD/A/PC/47' AND YEAR(DT_TAREFA)='2013'
              GROUP BY MONTH(DT_TAREFA);";
    $this->virtualFields['TOTAL'] = 0;
    //query de consulta 
    return($this->query($query));
    //var_dump($result);
    //return($result);
}
```